Issue upgrade mysql machine has no internet
I am upgrading Windows MySQL from version 8.0.21 to 8.0.36, but the paths are not located in C:. When using the offline installer, I am not given the option to upgrade, and the architecture is shown as not specified. Additionally, the machine does not have internet access.
Tried using the installer using CMD, but intall did not work correctly.
This is in a cluster

Uninstall old MySql, install new one. I don't think you can fix your installer in any way

I wish to not go that way, because it's in a cluster.
